# "Missing return type on function" for every React class method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I a stateful React component in my Typescript project. I lint it with ESLint using `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`. I've enabled the rule `@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type`.

My component looks similar to this:

```
interface Props = {
  name: string;
}

interface State = {
  score: number
}

class Person extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    score: 2,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

In the above component I get the ESLint error on the `componentDidMount` and `render` methods:

`Missing return type on function - @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type`

I quite like the lint rule in general, but surely I don't have to declare a return type for all these React methods. I have `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` installed, so aren't these return types covered already?

Comment: Have you checked the settings for an option to allow inherited types?

Comment: @AvinKavish I haven't checked that but will now. My ESLint extends are: `"plugin:react/recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"` so would have though this would be default?!

Comment: Oh I meant within the plugin you installed, never mind I just checked, it had no such option. You might want to consider opening an issue on GitHub and asking the authors directly.

Comment: @AvinKavish Okay, thanks for your help

Comment: This might help partially, https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/493

Comment: I think there must be a bug with it. Even with the extra options to allow inferred types it then errors on just the React methods and not my own custom ones, so if anything the extra options make it worse!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195369/discussion-between-avin-kavish-and-coop).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try writing the return type for render function as

```
render(): JSX.Element {
  // render code
}
```

This works for me!

Comment: I get `JSX is not defined`

Answer (score 4):

I just got it working by adding the rule into `.eslintrc.json` with

```
{ "allowTypedFunctionExpressions": true }
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
      "error",
      { "allowTypedFunctionExpressions": true }
    ]
  }
}
```

versions

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.10.2",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.10.2",
"eslint": "^6.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here as I have not personally used `@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type` but it's name sounds as if you need a `return` in every single function written, including the lifecycle methods. Remember that the ESLint and React are not the same. ESLint is simply running over your code to point out *potential* errors. The React library should still be able to run without issue if you do not include these `return` statements

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question. He is saying that type inference should work on the class as he is inheriting from `Component` which already defines these methods with return types

Comment: This is a linting issue, not about whether the code will run or not. `@types/react` defines the type for `componentDidMount ` including a return type. So how come linting it telling me to define it again?